# Bootstrap 4 eliminate white space from title

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

[image]

1. I would like to remove the white space between Table Title and Sub Titles.
2. Also Sub Title "Sub1" together with the icon should be left-aligned within the cell

   ```
         <div class="mdc-layout-grid__cell stretch-card mdc-layout-grid__cell--span-3">
           <div class="mdc-card p-0">
             <h6 class="card-title">Table title</h6>
             <div class="table-responsive">
               <table class="table">
                 <thead bgcolor="#aed581">
                   <tr>
                     <th>
                       <span class="text-left">Sub1</span>
                       <span class="material-icons refresh-icon">refresh</span>
                     </th>
                     <th>Sub2</th>
                   </tr>
                 </thead>
                 <tbody>
                   <tr>
                     <td class="text-left">A</td>
                     <td>18.5%</td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                     <td class="text-left">B</td>
                     <td>16.3%</td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                     <td class="text-left">V</td>
                     <td>15.5%</td>
                   </tr>
               </table>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
   ```

Comment: For left alignment you can do like this:
<th>
                    <span style='text-align:center'>Sub1</span>
                    <span class="material-icons refresh-icon">refresh</span>
                  </th>

Comment: Have you checked if the h6 "card-title" has any type of padding or margin? It is possible that the white space is due to that.
And the same with the th that contains the subtitle and the icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need do with some css for remove that space

apply this css into ur css file `margin-bottom: 0;` will remove space from `table-responsive` and `card title`

```
.card-title{
  background-color: #aed581;
  padding: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.fa-repeat{
  color: lightgray;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

and for icon i used font-awesome icon here is the CDN link

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css
```

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="mdc-layout-grid__cell stretch-card mdc-layout-grid__cell--span-3">
            <div class="mdc-card p-0">
              <h6 class="card-title">Table title</h6>
              <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table">
                  <thead bgcolor="#aed581">
                    <tr>
                      <th>
                      <i class="fa fa-repeat"></i>
                       Sub1
                        <!-- <span class="material-icons refresh-icon">refresh</span> -->
                      </th>
                      <th>Sub2</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="text-left">A</td>
                      <td>18.5%</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>B</td>
                      <td>16.3%</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>V</td>
                      <td>15.5%</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

You can edit or preview [code here](https://jsfiddle.net/rdv1n9sy/1/)